# How do I use a random variable created in c# in XAML?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am working on my first windows phone 7 application. I have used Expression Blend 4 to create a simple ball game. Now, what I am trying to do is change the ball position randomly every time the game is started.

Here is the code I have created in the CS file to generate a random number.

```
namespace Bouncing_Ball
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            return random.Next(50, 350);
        }
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the XAML file contains the code.

```
<Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Height="50" Canvas.Left="{Binding ElementName=RandomNumber}" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="217" Width="50">
```

this isn't working. I am new to windows phone 7 development any helps would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Binding, you can reference a property of your page's datacontext. The easiest way in your case is, I think, to make your page its own datacontext:

```
namespace Bouncing_Ball
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public int RandomNumber { get; set; }

        public int GenerateRandomNumber(int min, int max)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            return random.Next(min, max);
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.RandomNumber = GenerateRandomNumber(50, 350);
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Height="50" Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=RandomNumber}" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="217" Width="50">
```

Comment: thanks KooKiz. This is what I wanted. I was confused with the DataContext. Thanks for a easy explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

Create a property and a member variable. Call the RandomizeRandomNumber method on the Load event of the MainPage.

```
private int _randomNumber = 0;

public int RandomNumber
{
    get
    {
        return _randomNumber;
    }
    set
    {
        _randomNumber = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.RandomNumber);
    }
}

public void RandomizeRandomNumber()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    RandomNumber = rnd.Next(50, 350);
}
```

Bind the RandomNumber to the Path, not the ElementName.

```
<Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Height="50" Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=RandomNumber}" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="217" Width="50">
```

Sidenote: I would recommend to use the MVVM pattern when you develop WPF/Silverlight/WP7 applications. :-)

Comment: Thanks Rupo for your instant reply, very helpful.